# Asynchronous trigger (Change Data Capture)

Tags: trigger, asynchronous, change-data-capture

I have a asynchronous trigger on Sobject(Billing_Product__c) which works on CDC framework. Change event can be caused by insert, update or delete. How do I check inside trigger if the change event is caused by insert of sobject ?

```
trigger BillingProductsChangeTrigger on Billing_Product__ChangeEvent (after insert) {    

system.debug('IN BILLING PRODUCT CHANGE EVENT TRIGGER!!');
Set<String> bpIds = new Set<String>();

for (Billing_Product__ChangeEvent change : Trigger.new) {
    // Get all Record Ids for this change and add to the set
    List<String> recordIds = change.ChangeEventHeader.getRecordIds();
    bpIds.addAll(recordIds);
}
system.debug('bpIds ' + bpIds);
BillingProductClass.BillingProductsAfter(bpIds);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it from the change event header. Here's an example adapted from the [Change Data Capture Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_add_trigger.htm):

```
trigger MyAccountChangeTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    for (AccountChangeEvent event : Trigger.New) {
        EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = event.ChangeEventHeader;
        if (header.changetype == 'CREATE') {
        }        
        else if (header.changetype == 'UPDATE') {
        }     
    }
}
```

[Available change types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_event_fields_header.htm) are

- CREATE
- UPDATE
- DELETE
- UNDELETE

plus the gap event types.